# How can I use json child in flat list?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to show some data like date,time,... and products (name,type,price). Now I can't see anything when I use `item.product.name` in `flatlist`.
How can I show product name?

(flatlist need to object so I change data to object by `Object.values(responseJson)`)

```
componentDidMount(){

    fetch('https://example.com/',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        username:this.state.username,
        orderid:this.state.orderid,
      })
    }).then((response)=>response.json()).
    then((responseJson)=>{
      if(responseJson === "none"){
        this.setState({
        noneorder:true,
        });
      }else {
        this.setState({
          dataSource:Object.values(responseJson),
        });
      }
    }).catch((error)=>console.error(error));

  }
```

**Json (before change to object):**

```
{"20":{"id":"20","date":"12/11","time":"18:29:59","products":"{\"164\":{\"id\":\"164\",\"name\":\"\\u067e\\u06cc\\u0631\\u0627\\u0647\\u0646\",\"type\":\"\\u0627\\u062a\\u0648\",\"product\":\"1\",\"count\":\"1\",\"price\":3500}}","sum":"3500","status":"paid"}}
```

Flatlist:

```
 <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View>
           <Text>{item.date}</Text>
           <Text>{item.products.name}</Text>
      </View>
      }
 />
```

**Result is:** **12/11** But should be **12/11 mynameofproduct**

Comment: Currently is the name is shown below the date, or not at all?

Comment: @rabbit87 No I can't see the name. The flatlist does not support this type.I fix this problem by php but this question is really applied.

Comment: You fixed the problem? So it's working now?

Comment: @rabbit87 Yes,but by php! Now I use foreach in php to put name of product in new child like date.